# Refresh a div that is displayed with php

Tags: php

i want to refresh a page in php(which is executing the sql statements) to p refreshed every 10 seconds. I load the page in a div like:

```
<div id="test"> <?php echo showPage() ?></div>
```

So how can i just refresh this duv that will make the data fetch by the sql refresh..

thank you

Comment: if you want to include js, do ajax and setinterval

Comment: You can't just refresh a part of Web page ...

You can use Javascript Ajax request to get content and replace the current.. content in this div. And after that set that request to run in intervals..

Comment: Look at this link [refresh div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073784/get-file-contents-refresh-div?rq=1)

Comment: like every answer suggests, the best was it to use AJAX to refresh your DIV.  since you did not mention javascript at all, I am hesitant to offer that solution.  to refresh a single area without javascript, is possible with the use of an iFrame.  a meta refresh on an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Write your script in the below way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function () {
        $('#test').load('test.php');
    }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
<body>
<div id="test"> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: hi thanks, i tried it, but its not displaying anything.. please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can include a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/>` tag in the `head` tag, or, if you do not have access to the `head` tag, you can insert a `script` tag anywhere in the page like this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
}, 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: he wants to refresh the div not the full page.

Comment: true, but this is the only answer that does not use jQuery.

Comment: Cant there be answers which use plain javascript ? jQuery is library coded in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        $(document).ready(function() {
              setTimeout('$(\'#test\').load(\'abc.php #test >* \' )', 10000)
        });
        //--></script>
```